# How to use linq to return a boolean

Tags: c#, linq

I have a foreach loop where I'm iterating through a list to make sure every item is valid and want to return a boolean.

Here's my foreach code:

```
bool isValid = true;

foreach (var req in requestList)
{
    if (!req.ChannelId.HasValue || !req.PayoutAmountInCents.HasValue)
    {
        isValid = false;
        PayoutFDEvents.LogInvalidPayoutRequest(this.BuildPayoutFDDocument(req), "missing channelId or patronage amount");
    }
}
```

and here's my attempt to convert it to a linq statement:

```
var isValid = requestList
    .Select(r =>
    {
        if (!r.ChannelId.HasValue || !r.PayoutAmountInCents.HasValue)
        {
            PayoutFDEvents.LogInvalidPayoutRequest(this.BuildPayoutFDDocument(r), "missing channelId or patronage amount");
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    });
```

However, looks like my implementation returns a list of bools instead. Is there a way I can return an overall bool?

Comment: LINQ is not appropriate here because of the `PayoutFDEvents.LogInvalidPayoutRequest` call. That's a side effect and not part of the projection logic. Stick with the original `foreach` loop.

Comment: I'd like to to log all invalid items

Comment: Did either of the answers work for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could be converted to a simple expression like this:

```
var isValid = requestList.All(r => r.ChannelId.HasValue && r.PayoutAmountInCents.HasValue)
```

I would suggest you don't log something in the middle of your expression - this is just smelly and won't work very well once you convert to using `All()`

Comment: to better understand, what is the reason for not logging in my expression?

Comment: @RDoolabh It's separation of concerns. You could detect and log the problematic entries using a separate statement: `requestList.Where(r => r.ChannelId == null || r.PayoutAmountInCents == null).ForEach(r => PayoutFDEvents.LogInvalidPayoutRequest(this.BuildPayoutFDDocument(r), "missing channelId or patronage amount"));`

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this:

```
var invalids = requestList.Where(r => !(r.ChannelId.HasValue && r.PayoutAmountInCents.HasValue)).ToList();
invalids.ForEach(r => PayoutFDEvents.LogInvalidPayoutRequest(BuildPayoutFDDocument(r), "msg"));
bool isValid = invalids.Any();
```

I think your logic is too complex to be done in a one line statement.

Answer (score -1):

One option would be to use:

```
var isValid = requestList
          .Select(r => 
          {
              var valid =r.ChannelId.HasValue && r.PayoutAmountInCents.HasValue;
              if (!valid)
              {
                  PayoutFDEvents.LogInvalidPayoutRequest(
                      this.BuildPayoutFDDocument(req), "missing channelId or patronage amount");
              }
              return valid;
          })
          .DefaultIfEmpty(true)
          .Min();
```

Because `false` is "less" than `true`, this will return `false` if any of the individual entries meet the condition (i.e. are `null`).

*The `DefaultIfEmpty` bit is to handle the scenario where `requestList` is empty - in which case `isValid` will be set to `true`.*

*In all honesty though, since you are performing the logging inside your existing loop I would keep your existing code. It is simple, clear, and easy to read and understand.*